# How can I determine what kept my macbook pro awake until the battery drained?

Tags: sleep-wake, power-management

I left my laptop unplugged last night and woke up to 0% battery. This is not usually what happens. Is there a way I can find out, this time or next time, what caused that? I assume something was running that prevented it from going into low power or sleep mode.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following in Terminal:

```
pmset -g log
```

You'll be able to check if there was some activity during the night.